# How to schedule a Python script to run at a certain time?

Tags: python, scheduler, bots, reddit, praw

Hello I am very new to programming and i'm trying to make an auto-posting bot for my subreddit.I'm using praw and I need to run this script at certain times and have it input and work

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="UA")
r.login("username", "password")
sub = r.get_subreddit("Sub")
sub.submit("Title", text="Post text")
```

I'm running windows and someone said to use the task scheduler but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be great. Thank You.

Comment: If you are using Linux, try [crontab](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

Comment: I'm running windows unfortunately.

Comment: Then you could use the windows scheduler. If you want it to run in the background, pick `SYSTEM` for the run-as user.

Comment: I tried saving the above script as a .py file then running it with scheduler. It didn't work. It was supposed to post a test thread to my subreddit.

Comment: Have you tried entering the program to the path of your python executable, and passing the path to your script as the first command line argument? So that, your prompt looks like this `<path_to_python>/python.exe`, and the command line arguments look like this `<path_to_your_script>.py`.

Comment: "I haven't been able to figure it out" - how far have you got? Found Task Scheduler in the start menu yet? Don't make someone write out a list of instructions for the parts you don't need. Most likely error I can think of when setting up a scheduled task for Python is that you need to set the current directory.

Comment: So I scheduled a task to run the Test.py file. It worked and ran the file with the above code but nothing happened.

Comment: @user2991305: how do you know it really ran the code if nothing happened? Try adding code to print some output to a file, and debug using that.

Comment: Actually i don't. i just know that at the time i said for the task to run a black cmd prompt box popped up really fast then dissipated, all within about a half second. heres what i did...i opened task scheduler (screen shot) http://imgur.com/zpTy0SV.jpg and clicked browse. I then opened my python folder and selected my test bot .py file (screen shot) http://imgur.com/1MS36mz.png ..then i clicked next and chose one time only for it to run then inputed the time and clicked finish. sorry for the shitty xp screenshots..

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to look into sched, a general purpose event scheduler. It is described, with appropriate examples to start you, in the [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html).

Sample:

```
import time
import sched

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def reddit():
  <your code>

def scheduler_reddit():

  scheduler.enter(0, 1, reddit, ())
  scheduler.run()
  time.sleep(3600)

for i in range(100):
  scheduler_reddit()
```

Change 3600 with the desired time in seconds.

Comment: Thank you. I looked into this and seemed sorta confusing. I don't really know that much about code but I don't really want to take a long course to just be able to do one little thing. Do you mind telling me what I would have to input to get the above code to to be schduled at a certain time?

Comment: Ok... So where do i input the time for it to run? in (time.time, time.sleep)? how does that work...sorry for so many questions..haha

Comment: Ok I see you changed the code...I will test it out...thanks for your help friend!

Comment: Put your code in the reddit() function, save as .py, run it and it will execute your code every 60min(3600seconds). You can change the time by editing the value in time.sleep().

Comment: Ok. would i need to change the time if i'm just going to run it with scheduler?

Comment: The scheduler is implemented in the code hence before you run it you only need to add your code and set the appropriate time interval between runs. In general, you may not even need to use sched because of the simplicity of the task, but it allows  for future extensions of the script.

Comment: Ok. so I put the code in two bracket's <your code> but when i pressed enter it highlighted the left bracket in red and it says SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: @user2991305: You aren't supposed to type `<your code>`, that's where you put your code.

Comment: Yes i know i typed my code in between the brackets...i fixed it though. Here's a screenshot of the code http://imgur.com/OSGwWz6.jpg. I tried testing by running the .py file with task scheduler. no luck it didn't post to the subreddit..ps, i know your supposed to fill in the green blanks i just posted the template so you wouldn't know my account password.

Comment: Is there a way to make the script run without opening the ide / or having the ide from being open the whole time? (Something like running the script in the background)?

Comment: @powersource97 'nohup python filename.py &'

Comment: @powersource97 You can use `ps` and `grep` to get the pid of the process and kill it. For example, `ps aux | grep filename.py | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill -9`